# Meteor Publish-Composite nesting issue

Tags: meteor, meteor-collections

**Problem:** 
I have a number of groups that each have members that belong to different groups.  Each member has a title (role) in each group.
I’m trying to list all the groups and display each member in the group and their title.
I’m using reywood:publish-composite, and everything is working except I can’t get the title of each member to display.
I think the problem is in the Template.groupMembers.helpers file

```
 title: function() {
        console.log(this.roleId); // this shows up in the console for each member
        return Titles.findOne({titleId: this.roleId}); // but this doesn’t work 
      },
```

**Collections:**

```
groups {
    "_id" : "xFSzAHBEps2dSKcWM",
    "name" : "Generic Group",
    "logo" : "generic-logo-hi.png"
}


members {
    "_id" : "vyDtiaKKukZYQdFvs",
    "groupId" : "xFSzAHBEps2dSKcWM",
    "memberId" : "hRx8GBTyB5X8iQQ52",
    "roleId" : "1"
}


Meteor.users {
    "_id" : "hRx8GBTyB5X8iQQ52",
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "Bob Lorros"
    },
 }


titles {
    "_id" : "bYsKpsyYtyKR8NYpm",
    "titleId" : 1,
    "title" : "Staff (non-voting)"
}
```

server/publications/publications.js

```
Meteor.publishComposite('groupMembers', {
  find: function() {
      return Groups.find({}, {
        sort: {name: 1}
      });
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function() {
                return Titles.find();
            },
            find: function(group) {
              return Members.find({groupId: group._id});
            },
            children: [
              {
                find: function(member) {
                    return Meteor.users.find({_id: member.memberId});
                }
              },
            ]
        },
    ]
});
```

client/templates/test/test.js

```
Template.groupMembers.helpers({
  groupMembers: function() {
    return Groups.find({}, {
      sort: {name: 1}
    });
  },
  members: function() {
    return Members.find({groupId: this._id});
  },
  title: function() {
    console.log(this.roleId); // this shows up in the console for each member
    return Titles.findOne({titleId: this.roleId}); // but this doesn’t work 
  },
  memberName: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.memberId);
  },
});
```

client/templates/test/test.html

```
<template name="groupMembers">
  <h4>Group - Members</h4>
  {{#each groupMembers}}
    <b>{{name}}</b><br>
    {{#each members}}
       &nbsp;{{memberName.profile.name}}
        - title = {{title.title}}
        <br>
    {{/each}}
    <br>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Output :
[This is the ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn67o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this from a completely different perspective, I actually think you could use alanning:roles to accomplish exactly what you're looking for.  You can use the role as the 'title' in this case and the 'group' to replace your groups.  Here's the documentation:

https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: Thanks @StephenWoods - this looks like it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think your second `find` may be overriding your first. Instead of:

```
find: function() {
  return Titles.find();
},
find: function(group) {
  return Members.find({groupId: group._id});
},
```

Try returning an array of cursors.

```
find: function() {
  return [
    Titles.find(),
    Members.find({groupId: group._id})
  ];
},
```

I don't understand however why `Titles` is a child of `GroupMembers` when the query for titles is all titles. Did you mean to have a query there?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFloyd, but the array approach triggered an object error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your publishComposite is causing the problem, each object in the children array should have only one `find` and zero or more `children`. Also the second parameter in your publication must be a function and not a JSON object. Try this,

```
 Meteor.publishComposite('groupMembers', function () {
     return {
        find: function() {
            return Groups.find({}, {
               sort: {name: 1}
            });
        },
        children: [{
           find: function() {
              return Titles.find();
           }
        },
        {
           find: function(group) {
              return Members.find({groupId: group._id});
           },
           children: [{
              find: function(member) {
                 return Meteor.users.find({_id: member.memberId});
              }
           }]
        }]
     };
 });
```

You can also improve performance by moving `Titles.find` to the root level

```
    Meteor.publishComposite('groupMembers', function () {
     return [{
        find: function() {
           return Titles.find();
        }
     }, {
        find: function() {
            return Groups.find({}, {
               sort: {name: 1}
            });
        },
        children: [{
           find: function(group) {
              return Members.find({groupId: group._id});
           },
           children: [{
              find: function(member) {
                 return Meteor.users.find({_id: member.memberId});
              }
           }]
        }]
     }];
 });
```